# How to make Realm Database HIPAA compliant?

Tags: realm

Is ih possible to set up realm to be conpliant to HIPAA or the corresponding European laws for healthcare applications?

Answer (score 5):

*(Full Disclaimer: I work for Realm)*

While full HIPAA compliance depends on your infrastructure and architecture as a whole, Realm was designed with those sorts of high security requirements in mind.

If you're referring to just the Realm Local Database, Realm files on disk can be optionally encrypted using AES-256, which is more than enough for protecting confidential medical information.

If you're referring to the Realm Mobile Platform, then in addition to the on-disk encryption, synchronized data is also encrypted when transmitted between devices. <strike>This functionality is on by default and cannot be disabled.</strike> **Correction:** This functionality isn't on by default because you need to provide your own certificates, but is highly recommended.

One of the major aspects of HIPAA compliance is that the entity needs to be in complete control of the hardware in where the data is stored (ie, medical data cannot be saved on third party servers). At the time of writing, Realm is a package you deploy to your own servers, so you are always in control of your own data.

Comment: @tTiM is there any other documentation that can help PHI/HiPaa compliance, or perhaps examples of other customers storing PHI with realm. I'm trying to make the push at work that its ok  to store PHI using realm.

Comment: @WalterMartinVargas-Pena I don't work at Realm anymore, so I'd recommend you contact them and ask for any use-cases they can publicly talk about. :)